# dpdk rss flow over gre

Tags: dpdk, mellanox

I am using Mellanox Technologies MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5], using dpdk19.11 multi rx queue with rss "ETH_RSS_IP | ETH_RSS_UDP | ETH_RSS_TCP"

I receive packet with ETH:IP:GRE:ETH:***IP:UDP***

I want the load balancing to be according to inner ***ip+port*** and not with the gre ip

It is supported by dpdk 19.11 because i succeeded to do it with testpmd in link
[RSS hash for ip over gre packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71338802/rss-hash-for-ip-over-gre-packet)

```
 ethtool -i ens2
driver: mlx5_core
version: 5.5-1.0.3
firmware-version: 16.31.1014 (HPE0000000014)
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:03:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

When i try to test with my own code it doesn't work, testpmd is complex and i don't know what i am doing wrong

Here is a link to code that i wrote
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdeefd58b08063be

I run it with following command:
./testReceiver   --log-level='.*',8 -l 7,8-23   -w 0000:03:00.0

Here is output of of my code run with high log level

The behavior with my code, is that all packet are going to one queue and with tespmd it is spread over all rx queue

```
[root@localhost testReceiver]# ./testReceiver   --log-level='.*',8 -l 7,8-23   -w 0000:03:00.0
EAL: Detected lcore 0 as core 0 on socket 0
...
EAL: Detected lcore 63 as core 63 on socket 3
EAL: Support maximum 128 logical core(s) by configuration.
EAL: Detected 64 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 4 NUMA nodes
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x5000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x100000000 (size = 0x5000)
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: VFIO PCI modules not loaded
EAL: Bus pci wants IOVA as 'DC'
EAL: Buses did not request a specific IOVA mode.
EAL: IOMMU is available, selecting IOVA as VA mode.
EAL: Module /sys/module/rte_kni not found! error 2 (No such file or directory)
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL:   IOMMU type 1 (Type 1) is supported
EAL:   IOMMU type 7 (sPAPR) is not supported
EAL:   IOMMU type 8 (No-IOMMU) is not supported
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x2e000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x100005000 (size = 0x2e000)
EAL: Setting up physically contiguous memory...
EAL: Setting maximum number of open files to 4096
EAL: Detected memory type: socket_id:0 hugepage_sz:1073741824
EAL: Detected memory type: socket_id:1 hugepage_sz:1073741824
EAL: Detected memory type: socket_id:2 hugepage_sz:1073741824
EAL: Detected memory type: socket_id:3 hugepage_sz:1073741824
EAL: Creating 4 segment lists: n_segs:32 socket_id:0 hugepage_sz:1073741824
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x1000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x100033000 (size = 0x1000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x100000kB at socket 0
...
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x1a00000000 (size = 0x800000000)
EAL: Creating 4 segment lists: n_segs:32 socket_id:1 hugepage_sz:1073741824
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x1000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x2200000000 (size = 0x1000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x100000kB at socket 1
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x2240000000 (size = 0x800000000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x1000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x2a40000000 (size = 0x1000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x100000kB at socket 1
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x2a80000000 (size = 0x800000000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x1000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x3280000000 (size = 0x1000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x100000kB at socket 1
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x32c0000000 (size = 0x800000000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x1000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x3ac0000000 (size = 0x1000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x100000kB at socket 1
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x3b00000000 (size = 0x800000000)
EAL: Creating 4 segment lists: n_segs:32 socket_id:2 hugepage_sz:1073741824
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x1000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x4300000000 (size = 0x1000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x100000kB at socket 2
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x4340000000 (size = 0x800000000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x1000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x4b40000000 (size = 0x1000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x100000kB at socket 2
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x4b80000000 (size = 0x800000000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x1000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x5380000000 (size = 0x1000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x100000kB at socket 2
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x53c0000000 (size = 0x800000000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x1000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x5bc0000000 (size = 0x1000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x100000kB at socket 2
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x5c00000000 (size = 0x800000000)
EAL: Creating 4 segment lists: n_segs:32 socket_id:3 hugepage_sz:1073741824
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x1000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x6400000000 (size = 0x1000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x100000kB at socket 3
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x6440000000 (size = 0x800000000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x1000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x6c40000000 (size = 0x1000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x100000kB at socket 3
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x6c80000000 (size = 0x800000000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x1000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7480000000 (size = 0x1000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x100000kB at socket 3
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x74c0000000 (size = 0x800000000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x1000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7cc0000000 (size = 0x1000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x100000kB at socket 3
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x800000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x7d00000000 (size = 0x800000000)
EAL: TSC frequency is ~2000000 KHz
EAL: Master lcore 7 is ready (tid=7ffff7fe7900;cpuset=[7])
EAL: lcore 13 is ready (tid=7ffff247a700;cpuset=[13])
EAL: lcore 18 is ready (tid=7fffefc75700;cpuset=[18])
EAL: lcore 21 is ready (tid=7fffee472700;cpuset=[21])
EAL: lcore 10 is ready (tid=7ffff3c7d700;cpuset=[10])
EAL: lcore 11 is ready (tid=7ffff347c700;cpuset=[11])
EAL: lcore 8 is ready (tid=7ffff4c7f700;cpuset=[8])
EAL: lcore 22 is ready (tid=7fffedc71700;cpuset=[22])
EAL: lcore 23 is ready (tid=7fffed470700;cpuset=[23])
EAL: lcore 19 is ready (tid=7fffef474700;cpuset=[19])
EAL: lcore 14 is ready (tid=7ffff1c79700;cpuset=[14])
EAL: lcore 12 is ready (tid=7ffff2c7b700;cpuset=[12])
EAL: lcore 15 is ready (tid=7ffff1478700;cpuset=[15])
EAL: lcore 17 is ready (tid=7ffff0476700;cpuset=[17])
EAL: lcore 16 is ready (tid=7ffff0c77700;cpuset=[16])
EAL: lcore 9 is ready (tid=7ffff447e700;cpuset=[9])
EAL: lcore 20 is ready (tid=7fffeec73700;cpuset=[20])
EAL: Trying to obtain current memory policy.
EAL: Setting policy MPOL_PREFERRED for socket 0
EAL: Restoring previous memory policy: 0
EAL: request: mp_malloc_sync
EAL: Heap on socket 0 was expanded by 1024MB
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.0 on NUMA socket 3
EAL:   probe driver: 15b3:1017 net_mlx5
EAL: Mem event callback 'MLX5_MEM_EVENT_CB:(nil)' registered
net_mlx5: checking device "mlx5_0"
net_mlx5: PCI information matches for device "mlx5_0"
net_mlx5: no E-Switch support detected
net_mlx5: naming Ethernet device "0000:03:00.0"
net_mlx5: DevX is supported
EAL: Trying to obtain current memory policy.
EAL: Setting policy MPOL_PREFERRED for socket 3
EAL: Restoring previous memory policy: 0
EAL: Calling mem event callback 'MLX5_MEM_EVENT_CB:(nil)'
EAL: request: mp_malloc_sync
EAL: Heap on socket 3 was expanded by 1024MB
net_mlx5: enhanced MPW is supported
net_mlx5: SWP support: 7
net_mlx5:       min_single_stride_log_num_of_bytes: 6
net_mlx5:       max_single_stride_log_num_of_bytes: 13
net_mlx5:       min_single_wqe_log_num_of_strides: 3
net_mlx5:       max_single_wqe_log_num_of_strides: 16
net_mlx5:       supported_qpts: 256
net_mlx5: device supports Multi-Packet RQ
net_mlx5: tunnel offloading is supported
net_mlx5: MPLS over GRE/UDP tunnel offloading is not supported
net_mlx5: checksum offloading is supported
net_mlx5: maximum Rx indirection table size is 512
net_mlx5: VLAN stripping is supported
net_mlx5: FCS stripping configuration is supported
net_mlx5: enhanced MPS is enabled
net_mlx5: port 0 MAC address is b8:83:03:8f:4e:f0
net_mlx5: port 0 MTU is 2040
net_mlx5: port 0 forcing Ethernet interface up
net_mlx5: Tx VLAN insertion is supported
net_mlx5: min tx inline configured: 0
net_mlx5: Hash list with mlx5_0_flow_table size 0x1000 is created.
net_mlx5: Hash list with mlx5_0_tags size 0x2000 is created.
net_mlx5: port 0 flow maximum priority: 5
net_mlx5: metadata mode 0
net_mlx5: metadata MARK mask 00FFFFFF
net_mlx5: metadata META mask FFFFFFFF
net_mlx5: metadata reg_c0 mask FFFFFFFF
net_mlx5: port 0 extensive metadata register is not supported
net_mlx5: DR drop action is not supported in root table.
net_mlx5: port 0 Tx queues number update: 0 -> 1
net_mlx5: port 0 Rx queues number update: 0 -> 4
net_mlx5: port 0 adapter MTU set to 2040
net_mlx5: port 0 configuring Rx queue 0 for 512 descriptors
net_mlx5: port 0 maximum number of segments per packet: 1
net_mlx5: port 0 CRC stripping is disabled, 4 bytes will be subtracted from incoming frames to hide it
net_mlx5: port 0 adding Rx queue 0 to list
net_mlx5: port 0 configuring Rx queue 1 for 512 descriptors
net_mlx5: port 0 maximum number of segments per packet: 1
net_mlx5: port 0 CRC stripping is disabled, 4 bytes will be subtracted from incoming frames to hide it
net_mlx5: port 0 adding Rx queue 1 to list
net_mlx5: port 0 configuring Rx queue 2 for 512 descriptors
net_mlx5: port 0 maximum number of segments per packet: 1
net_mlx5: port 0 CRC stripping is disabled, 4 bytes will be subtracted from incoming frames to hide it
net_mlx5: port 0 adding Rx queue 2 to list
net_mlx5: port 0 configuring Rx queue 3 for 512 descriptors
net_mlx5: port 0 maximum number of segments per packet: 1
net_mlx5: port 0 CRC stripping is disabled, 4 bytes will be subtracted from incoming frames to hide it
net_mlx5: port 0 adding Rx queue 3 to list
testReceiver.cpp 94
net_mlx5: port 0 configuring queue 0 for 512 descriptors
net_mlx5: port 0 adding Tx queue 0 to list
net_mlx5: port 0 starting device
net_mlx5: port 0 Rx queues number update: 4 -> 4
net_mlx5: port 0 Tx queue 0 allocated and configured 512 WRs
net_mlx5: port 0 Tx queue 0 TIS number 9 transport domain 2
net_mlx5: port 0: uar_mmap_offset 0x306000
net_mlx5: port 0 Rx queue 0 registering mp pool having 1 chunks
net_mlx5: port 0 creating a MR using address (0x15aa07e80)
net_mlx5: device mlx5_0 inserting MR(0x15a9f7e00) to global cache
net_mlx5: inserted B-tree(0x17ffdcb60)[1], [0x140000000, 0x180000000) lkey=0xa3c41800
net_mlx5: inserted B-tree(0x15aa0686c)[1], [0x140000000, 0x180000000) lkey=0xa3c41800
net_mlx5: port 0 Rx queue 0 allocated and configured 512 segments (max 512 packets)
net_mlx5: port 0 device_attr.max_qp_wr is 32768
net_mlx5: port 0 device_attr.max_sge is 30
net_mlx5: port 0 rxq 0 updated with 0x7fffffffd578
net_mlx5: port 0 Rx queue 1 registering mp pool having 1 chunks
net_mlx5: inserted B-tree(0x15aa03fec)[1], [0x140000000, 0x180000000) lkey=0xa3c41800
net_mlx5: port 0 Rx queue 1 allocated and configured 512 segments (max 512 packets)
net_mlx5: port 0 device_attr.max_qp_wr is 32768
net_mlx5: port 0 device_attr.max_sge is 30
net_mlx5: port 0 rxq 1 updated with 0x7fffffffd578
net_mlx5: port 0 Rx queue 2 registering mp pool having 1 chunks
net_mlx5: inserted B-tree(0x15aa0176c)[1], [0x140000000, 0x180000000) lkey=0xa3c41800
net_mlx5: port 0 Rx queue 2 allocated and configured 512 segments (max 512 packets)
net_mlx5: port 0 device_attr.max_qp_wr is 32768
net_mlx5: port 0 device_attr.max_sge is 30
net_mlx5: port 0 rxq 2 updated with 0x7fffffffd578
net_mlx5: port 0 Rx queue 3 registering mp pool having 1 chunks
net_mlx5: inserted B-tree(0x15a9feeec)[1], [0x140000000, 0x180000000) lkey=0xa3c41800
net_mlx5: port 0 Rx queue 3 allocated and configured 512 segments (max 512 packets)
net_mlx5: port 0 device_attr.max_qp_wr is 32768
net_mlx5: port 0 device_attr.max_sge is 30
net_mlx5: port 0 rxq 3 updated with 0x7fffffffd578
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 new rx matcher 0x15a9c1940: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 new rx matcher 0x15a9c1480: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 new rx matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9c1480: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 new rx matcher 0x15a9cd380: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 new rx matcher 0x15a9d6e00: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 new rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6e00: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 use rx matcher 0x15a9c1940: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9c1480: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 4++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 5++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9c1480: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 6++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 7++
net_mlx5: port 0 has selected Tx function supporting offloads 0100/0100
net_mlx5:       EMPW  (Enhanced MPW)
net_mlx5: port 0 selected Rx vectorized function
net_mlx5: port 0 setting primary MAC address
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 8--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 7--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1480: refcnt 4--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 6--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 5--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1480: refcnt 3--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1940: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 4--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 3--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6e00: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6940: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6e00: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6e00: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cd380: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cd380: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 4--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 3--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1480: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cae00: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1480: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1480: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1940: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1940: removed
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 new rx matcher 0x15a9d9880: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 new rx matcher 0x15a9d93c0: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 new rx matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9d93c0: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 new rx matcher 0x15a9ca400: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 new rx matcher 0x15a9e2e00: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 new rx matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9e2e00: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 use rx matcher 0x15a9d9880: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9d93c0: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 4++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 5++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9d93c0: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 6++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 7++
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 8--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 7--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d93c0: refcnt 4--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 6--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 5--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d93c0: refcnt 3--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9880: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 4--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 3--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2e00: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2940: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2e00: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2e00: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9ca400: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9ca400: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 4--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 3--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d93c0: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1e00: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1e00: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d93c0: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d93c0: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9880: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9880: removed
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 new rx matcher 0x15a9cd880: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 new rx matcher 0x15a9cd3c0: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 new rx matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9cd3c0: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 new rx matcher 0x15a9c1340: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 new rx matcher 0x15a9d6e00: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 new rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6e00: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 use rx matcher 0x15a9cd880: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9cd3c0: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 4++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 5++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9cd3c0: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 6++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 7++
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 8--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 7--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cd3c0: refcnt 4--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 6--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 5--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cd3c0: refcnt 3--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cd880: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 4--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 3--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6e00: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6940: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6e00: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d6e00: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1340: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9c1340: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 4--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 3--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cd3c0: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9d40: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9d40: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cd3c0: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cd3c0: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cd880: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cd880: removed
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 new rx matcher 0x15a9ca940: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 new rx matcher 0x15a9ca480: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 new rx matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9ca480: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 new rx matcher 0x15a9d9340: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 new rx matcher 0x15a9e2e00: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 new rx matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9e2e00: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 use rx matcher 0x15a9ca940: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9ca480: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 4++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 5++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9ca480: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 6++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 7++
Succeeded to start port0
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 8--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 7--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9ca480: refcnt 4--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 6--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 5--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9ca480: refcnt 3--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9ca940: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 4--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 3--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2e00: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2940: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2940: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2e00: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9e2e00: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9340: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9d9340: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 4--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 3--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9ca480: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 2--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cdd40: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9cdd40: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9ca480: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9ca480: removed
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9ca940: refcnt 1--
net_mlx5: port 0 matcher 0x15a9ca940: removed
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 new rx matcher 0x15a9c1940: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 new rx matcher 0x15a9c1480: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 new rx matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9c1480: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9cae00: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 new rx matcher 0x15a9cd380: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 new rx matcher 0x15a9d6e00: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 new rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6e00: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 new rx matcher 0x15a9d9680: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 new rx matcher 0x15a9d91c0: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 new rx matcher 0x15a9e2b40: refcnt 1
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9e2b40: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9d91c0: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9e2b40: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9e2b40: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 14 use rx matcher 0x15a9cd380: refcnt 1++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6e00: refcnt 2++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 4++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 5++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 13 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6e00: refcnt 3++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 6++
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 12 use rx matcher 0x15a9d6940: refcnt 7++
Succeded to validate flow
net_mlx5: NIC group 0 priority 0 new rx matcher 0x15a9ee300: refcnt 1
Succeded to create flow
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the code link, quick check shows `rte_flow_create` is done, can we also cross check if we are enabling RSS (inner) as discussed with mellanox driver (mlx5)

Comment: If you are speaking about ETH_RSS_LEVEL_INNERMOST  it is not part of dpdk19, because testpmd succeeded i beleive it is not needed

Comment: I meant in DPDK mellanox driver `rss_conf.level` based on HAVE_IBV_DEVICE_TUNNEL_SUPPORT it can be either level 1 or level 2. while in device configuration `rss_hf |= RTE_ETH_RSS_LEVEL_INNERMOST;`. I will try to produce the behaviour with skeleton example and update

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on dpdk mailing list.
After setting all pattern[*].spec=NULL  traffic is spread among the rx queues.

Comment: nice to hear. thank you for sharing

Comment: quick question, as per the current code `actions[0].type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_RSS; actions[0].conf = &rss_conf; actions[1].type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_END;` how does this pass for `rte_flow_validate`. mellanox PMD should have failed it.

Comment: If you think it should be something else let me know

Comment: my expectation is if the RTE_FLOW_ACTION is not terminated with NULL the `rte_flow_validate` should fail (which happens with Intel and broadcom NIC), So my expectation is it should fail for Mellanox also.